# How to generate unique name in Faker based on a seed?

Tags: python, faker

I need to generate a fake username based on unique user attribute. For simplicity, let's assume each user in my system has an ID, and I want to generate fake names for them based on this attribute. I can't understand if it's possible.

In other words, I want something like this:

```py
f = Faker()

# pseudocode:
f.name(1) # -> "George Cook"
f.name(2) # -> "Sarah Johnson"
f.name(1) # -> "George Cook"
```

I tried to use `Faker.seed(value)`, but it still generates me random value each consequent invokation. I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve what I want though.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, just realised I just have to set the seed each time before fetching a username. So:

```py
>>> f.seed_instance('12312sdf3')
>>> f.name()
'Joshua Gray'
>>> 
>>> f.seed_instance('12312sdf3')
>>> f.name()
'Joshua Gray'
```